# Why shouldn't I release my app to all countries?

Tags: mobile, release

When releasing a mobile app on iPhone and Android, you can specify which countries you want to release your app to. Intuitively, you may want to just release it to all countries.

One example of why you should not release it to all countries (with made up numbers):

Your app uses ad revenue. You gain $0.03 per user in the United States. You gain $0.01 per user in India. Your server costs you about $0.02 per user. So you would want to release in the United States, but not India in this case.

Why else shouldn't I release my app to all countries?

*Disclaimer: This is not specifically a game development question, but it was the most fitting site I found.*

Comment: List questions aren't well-suited to our Q&A format.

Comment: Closing as per [this comment](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/do-we-want-to-lower-the-amount-votes-to-close-reopen-a-question#comment6978_2850).

Answer (score 3):

- You might want to release localized versions of your game in different countries. You could of course always create an universal version which auto-detects the locale settings of the user. But you might have voice-overs in multiple languages which can result in a pretty hefty filesize if you include them all. Or you might have some cultural changes to the game which require more than your i18n system can handle and require different content and programming for different locales.
- Marketing strategy. You might have limited marketing resources, so you want to stagger releases around the globe to better utilize them. A possible strategy can be to release in one country at the time so you can focus 100% of your marketing resources on that one country and then move to the next country after a couple weeks.
- When your game is an action-oriented multiplayer game, then it might be crucial for the game experience that the players have a good ping to the server. You don't want players to give you bad reviews because they live too far away from any servers to play properly. So you don't give them the game until you have a server in their country.
- Legal reasons. You might not be able to release your game in certain countries without getting into legal trouble. Perhaps your game violates a local trademark or a software patent. Perhaps you bough an IP license which isn't valid all around the globe. Or perhaps your game itself violates some laws in some countries. Either with its content (nudity, violence, blasphemy, drug use, hate speech, political activism...) or its features (gambling, privacy violation, money laundering...).

Comment: Another reason would be content legal reasons like gambling licenses or inappropriately content (sex/ drugs/ politics).

Comment: @Zibelas That's what I meant with the last sentence of the last bullet point of my question. I added some more examples to make it clearer what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a “soft-launch” of an app by releasing it only to a smaller country that has a similar demographic to your main audience. In the past, I have worked on projects released to just Canada, just New Zealand, and just Ireland, (they were games with different expected demographics based on genre).

This can be done as a public beta to iron out any kinks and to monitor user behavior, adjusting features (eg. gameplay, for balance) with a smaller set of users affected by the changes.

Once you are confident that you’re ready, you can then launch it worldwide.